# ssh login using wrong (and weird) user@host

Tags: authentication, ssh, remote-server

I'm having trouble accessing a remote server.  It appears to be trying to login with a weird user@host.  It is in the format `<myuser>\<myuser>@<server>` where `<myuser>` is my windows login.  It should be `<remoteUser>@<server>` which is specified in my config file.  Here is the message when I try to open the remote server.  My windows login is `mlap`. `oracle.usbx.me` is the remote hostname which is correct.

```
mlap\mlap@oracle.usbx.me's password:
```

My config file is below.  I know it is getting the correct config file because when I change the Host field the name in the sidebar changes.

```
Host usb
    HostName oracle.usbx.me
    User xobtlu
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile \users\mlap\.ssh\config
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  I had `IdentityFile \users\mlap\.ssh\config` instead of `IdentityFile \users\mlap\.ssh\id_rsa`.  I might have figured this out if the user name wasn't so weird.  I was looking at the username instead of the IdentityFile.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accepting your own answers to your own questions. They all seem helpful. You'll gain reputation points. Good luck.